# Laser Printer Scanner Brother DCP-8110DN Ubuntu. What is its URI?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

This computer uses Ubuntu 12.10 32bits, and the printer connected with Ethernet.

**Note: I had to install first csh and tcsh.

I have followed these instructions: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00104

This is the automated procedure, at the end of the installation process it asks if I will specify the URI, and following the instructions in the linked page I said Yes.

This is what the terminal asks then:

```
Will you specify the Device URI? [y/N] ->Y

0: ipp
1: ipps
2: lpd
3: socket
4: beh
5: hp
6: https
7: ipp14
8: smb
9: http
10: hpfax
11 (I): Specify IP address.
select the number of destination Device URI. ->6
```

I typed 6, but I really do not know why or what to choose.

Help please.

Any other tip on how to install this printer.

The other option I have is to follow the default procedure from Brother.com, but those instructions expand over and over on these pages, way too complicated for an average user, office user like myself.

I understand I should choose CUPS, I want to connect with Ethernet as I have several computer in my house's LAN.

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-8110DN
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/before.html#002
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html

Comment: Please clarify. Is the printer connected by ethernet to your router?

Comment: I think you should choose 11 and then type your printer's IP address.

Comment: See also:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167674/finding-device-printers-device-uri-during-driver-installation
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191026/specify-device-uri-for-brother-printer

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the printer is attached by ethernet to the router, I suggest you go into the administration pages of the router and determine the printers IP address. If you have the option to reserve the IP address used by the printer, please do so. For example: http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/Netgear/WNR2000v3/Address_Reservation.jpg

Then I would select option #0 for ipp. I would then use:

```
ipp://<IP address of printer>:631/binary_p1
```

The 'binary_p1' part comes from Brother's page you linked. You should then be asked for your printer's name; I suggest any name you and others on the LAN recognize; perhaps Brother8110.

Test by printing a test page.

Answer (score 1):

I just re-installed my Brother HL-3075CW drivers after getting a replacement computer. I'd forgotten how I got it working in the first place. However, what finally worked was when I selected number 11, which for me was: 11: lpd://BRW61D81946A4AB/BINARY_P1
(I noticed that the order of the options changes every time I installed the driver.)

The long string of characters is how my wireless router identifies my printer and the printer's host name that pops up when I initially tried to add the printer manually.

I'm somewhat sure that the lpd is what I chose on my old computer when printing finally worked. However, I'm doing this via wifi, rather than ethernet, so I can't guarantee this will be the right option for the OP or others. Also, different printer, different Ubuntu version, etc. I'm not a newbie to Linux, but connecting printers is one of those things I've never been able to do without hair-pulling, regardless of OS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried different protocols, but unfortunately only the option 11 `(Specify IP address.)` worked for me.
The DeviceURI for my printer is `socket://192.168.0.199`. 
I found the IP address of my printer(MFC-J1045DW) in its settings.

Comment: This was the only option that worked for my MFC-7440N

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue wih a Brother DCP-9020CDW and I solved it using    "ipp:///ipp/port1:" and proceeded as follows

- Configure WIFI on the printer and get the IP address
- download the linux brother software from brother web site (linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz)
- Uncompress and execute linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 script
- Select default settings and DO NOT select DEVICEURI option
- Once installed, check that the printer works properly using usb mode
- go to http://localhost:631/ in order to set up your Wifi connection
- Go to printers, select your printer, click on administration button and select "modify printer"
- Then, select Internet Printing Protocol (ipp) and click on continue.
- Replace "ipp" by "ipp:///ipp/port1" then continue and validate modifications
- List item

.... and you're done !