# Finding device printer's device URI during driver installation

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing

I'm trying to install a printer from Brother (model MFC-J470DW). I've been to Brother's site, downloaded and unzipped the *.gz driver file. Now it's asking if I want to specify the device URI.

Other posts show that you can choose no for a USB printer. I have a network printer, so I think I need to specify one. But the posts just stop there and say that "it works". I still can't print.

What is "the device URI" and how do I find it?

**[update1:]** Thanks, gmelodie.  The tutorial didn't help.  Below is the output from lpinfo command and the options in the install procedure. What should I use?

**[update2:]** I still can't print. What can I do?

[image: screen print1]
[image: screen print2]

Comment: See also:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/314314/laser-printer-scanner-brother-dcp-8110dn-ubuntu-what-is-its-uri
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191026/specify-device-uri-for-brother-printer

Answer (score 7):

From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-7761/fwmxi/index.html):

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is an addressing technology for identifying resources on the Internet or a private intranet. The terms URI and URL are used synonymously.

Also, from the [driver's manual page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=mfcj470dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625):

> Step7. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation
>   screen directions. When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",
>
> For **USB Users**: Choose **N(No)**
>
> For **Network Users**: Choose **Y(Yes)** and **DeviceURI** number.

So I'm assuming you are not using USB (because if you are this would be as simple as pressing '(N)o'), so in order to use your printer on the network you have to

### Getting device URI

Try

```
sudo lpinfo -v
```

The output should be something like (here is the output for my PC)

```
network https
network ipp
network http
network ipps
network lpd
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
direct parallel:/dev/lp0
network smb
network beh
network socket
direct hp
direct hpfax
```

Just look for a line that has `Brother` in it (like `usb://Brother/MFC-7360N?serial=U62700H1N772098`), that should be the one.

### Using linux's native GUI (`system-config-printer`)

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-manage-printers-linux/)

Answer (score 4):

For others who struggle with this:

**The problem was the printer's network connection.**

I don't know how it was lost. **To find the ip address/URI on this printer**:

- Menu
- Network
- WLAN
- TCP/IP
- IP Address

Now I have two printers with different URIs that both work:

- socket://##.#.#.###
- ipp://BRW3468956A95AA.local:631/ipp/print

The output of gmelodie's lpinfo command is now:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't working for you, try to find your printer's IP address (do this using the menu on your printer) and type in socket:// followed by the IP address. This finally got mine working when the URI wouldn't show from the above methods.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Brother installation tool.
When I got to ''will you supply the URI, Y or n'' I had done the ''sudo lpinfo-v'' in another terminal window and found the URI , but actually when I typed ''Y'' and entered, the tool gave me the same information that  I had found with ''lpinfo-v'' with each line numbered. Enter the line number and the process completed and test printed.