# Specify Device URI for brother printer

Tags: 18.04, printing

My brother printer won’t print over network so I’ve tried to reinstall the driver on my laptop. It asks me to specify my device’s URI, and I think this is what is stopping it from working - I can’t work out what to put in here!

Help would be appreciated. Running Ubuntu 18.04, printer is a brother printer.

Comment: See also:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/314314/laser-printer-scanner-brother-dcp-8110dn-ubuntu-what-is-its-uri
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167674/finding-device-printers-device-uri-during-driver-installation

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the Brother printer installation package (with a name something like `linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1`) you are asked to "Provide a URI?", the answer to that is `yes`.

You will then get a list of options (on my system around 14 or so):

- If the printer is switched on (if it isn't switch it on and start again!) one of the options will be (something like)

  ```
  12: socket://192.168.1.254
  ```

  and you'll be asked to select the number of destination device. Enter the option number (in this case `12`) and the installation will continue.
- If that option is not available another option will be (something like)

  ```
  13 (I): Specify IP address
  ```

  Type in the option number (here `13`) and then the IP address of the printer (which you'll probably be able to get from the printer) and the installation will continue.

Comment: The answer is NO if your printer is connected via USB!